# How to get a dialog box to read csv

Tags: python

I was wondering how I would go about allowing and prompting the user with a dialog box that allows for them to choose any csv file from any directory and being able to read that csv file?

Comment: You'll need a GUI library, like Qt or Tkinter

Comment: Here the solution , kindly check it , [External Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893894/opening-and-reading-a-csv-file-using-read-csv-from-tkinter-gui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you not using any GUI library? You'll need one for a "dialogue box" to prompt the user. Unless you just want them to enter filepaths in the command line as a string.

There's the Tkinter library, which has this function.
https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/

```
from tkinter import filedialog


filepath =  filedialog.askopenfilename()
```