# Tkinter - passing 3 user input variables to functions to search a csv file via a pandas query

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, tkinter-entry

**What I am trying to do:** The user enters the file path to a csv, a field name, and then a keyword/phrase and clicks submit....what is returned are the results of a pandas query structured using their input which reads from the csv they want to use.

**My code so far:**

```
# Relevant Python libraries:
import pandas as pd
import csv
import tkinter as tk
    
fieldname = tk.StringVar()
keyword = tk.StringVar()
csv_file_path = tk.StringVar() 

def import_csv_data(self):
    ?????
    ?????
    df = pd.dataframe(pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)) # not sure this is possible, need to define pandas dataframe somewhere? 

def search(self):
    print(df[df[fieldname.get()].str.contains(keyword.get()), na=False)] 

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Search CSV")
frm_form = tk.Frame(relief=tk.SUNKEN, borderwidth=3)
frm_form.pack()
        
   labels = [
       "CSV File Path:",
       "Field Name:",
       "Keyword/Phrase:",
   ]
    
 # Loop over the list of field labels
 for idx, text in enumerate(labels):
       # Create a Label widget with the text from the labels list
       label = tk.Label(master=frm_form, text=text)
        
       # Create an Entry widget
       entry = tk.Entry(master=frm_form, width=50)
       # Use the grid geometry manager to place the Label and
       # Entry widgets in the row whose index is idx
       label.grid(row=idx, column=0, sticky="ew")
       entry.grid(row=idx, column=1, sticky="ew")
    
 frm_buttons = tk.Frame()
 frm_buttons.pack(fill=tk.X, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
    
 btn_submit = tk.Button(master=frm_buttons, 
                        text="Submit", variable = csv_file_path, fieldname, keyword ) # HELP?
                       #command=lambda:[import_csv_data(self), search(self)]) #define a function and 
                       # insert at top to pull from from CSV and call with "command", bind for simplicity

 btn_submit.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, ipadx=10)
                           
 btn_clear = tk.Button(master=frm_buttons, text="Clear")
 btn_clear.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, ipadx=10)
    
 window.mainloop()
```

**Where I am stuck:** defining the functions that will do the work. I have no idea how to lay them out.
So, the first function would be to get the csv file and pass into a pandas dataframe...

The second function would get the field name (column) and the keyword and put it into something that looks like this:

```
print(df[df["fieldnamehere"].str.contains("thisphraseorkeyword", na=False)]
```

What I have found online so far doesn't have an example of how to get the input information into the function. I have labored searching for this situation and haven't had any luck. I don't have the skill to find related examples for one part and make it my own, I'm not there yet. I've also watched the first few parts of this YouTube tutorial by sentdex to help get me this far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oV68QJJUXTU as did this RealPython tutorial: https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/

This answer seemed helpful, but not sure to apply it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40894757

**Ask:** Any assistance with the functions and how to get the user input into the pandas string would be greatly appreciated. What I have written for the functions is kind of a guess.
I am not sure how to use the get() within the functions to make sure it does what is intended.
I hope this question is good enough, I've been editing it for an hour, ha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this

```py
def import_csv_data():
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(csv_file_path.get()))
    search(df)

def search(df):
    print(df[df[fieldname.get()].astype(str).str.contains(keyword.get())])
```

You would need to define the `StringVar`s after defining `tk.Tk` so that root is defined.

```py
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Search CSV")
frm_form = tk.Frame(relief=tk.SUNKEN, borderwidth=3)
frm_form.pack()

csv_file_path = tk.StringVar() 
fieldname = tk.StringVar()
keyword = tk.StringVar()
```

Since you are creating the `Entry` fields in a loop, you can use a dictionary and assign the `textvariable`

```py
labels = {
   "CSV File Path:":csv_file_path,
   "Field Name:":fieldname,
   "Keyword/Phrase:":keyword,
}
    
for idx, text in enumerate(labels.keys()):
    label = tk.Label(master=frm_form, text=text)
    entry = tk.Entry(master=frm_form, width=50, textvariable=labels[text])
    label.grid(row=idx, column=0, sticky="ew")
    entry.grid(row=idx, column=1, sticky="ew")
```

For the button, you can simply use the `import_csv_data` function as the command

```py
btn_submit = tk.Button(master=frm_buttons, 
                    text="Submit",command=import_csv_data)
```

Comment: Is "search(df)" in the import_csv_data function where the search function is called?

Comment: The `search` function is defined outside `import_csv_data`. In the `import_csv_data` function, `df` is defined and then passed on to the `search` function with the call `search(df)`. Does this help in answering your question?

Comment: It does. Another question to print the result to a csv, as well as in the notebook, I tried `def save(df):
    df.to_csv('jira_request.csv', index = False)` but it doesn't appear to save a file anywhere, and defining a desktop location wouldn't work if someone else were to open this and run it on their machine. Is it possible to also have a csv output?

Comment: The file would have been saved in the same directory as the script. Are you sure there is no file saved? What does this return `os.path.isfile('jira_request.csv')`?

Comment: It returns false. I am running jupyter as administrator too.

Comment: I just tried this in jupyter and it works fine. It could be that the current working directory used by jupyter in your case is not the same as where the `.ipynb` is located, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57503052/14094985) post explains it well.